# How to stop AsyncTask inside fragment A from another fragment B

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment

I could access all the fragments objects in the activity .. but I want when click on button in `Fragment A` to stop the running `AsyncTask` in `Fragment B` .. how is possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fragments` should not directly interact with on another; it is the `Activity`'s task to manage `Fragments`.

That being said, you could use an event bus like [`Otto`](http://square.github.io/otto/), to send "messages" to other parts of your application.

It differs from a `Broadcast Receiver` because there is no IPC overhead, sort of like using `LocalBroadcastManager`, but more reusable.

You can also use interfaces, but why do so when you can use an event bus and have components 
as loosely coupled as possible.

Comment: I swear by [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), and using something like it or Otto would be an easy way to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, keep a reference of the task you fire off. You can then use `AsyncTask.cancel` to cancel the task when the button is pressed. Cancelling here just prevents `onPostExecute` from being called after `doInBackground` and results in `onCancelled` being called instead.

However, if you need to cancel the task **during** `doInBackground`, you can extend `AsyncTask` with your own class and use a boolean and a setter. Depending on the nature of your task, you can check the boolean at different points in `doInBackground` and handle cancellation appropriately.

It may also be simpler to use lifecycle callbacks such as `onDestroyView` or `onDetach` (on the first fragment) to cancel the task.

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer **[communicating using interfaces, same as this link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)**,

You need to define a interface for Stoping AsyncTask, on receiving callback from Fragment B to stop AsyncTask, your activity can ask fragment A to stop AsyncTask.

Comment: In my opinion it is better to use an event bus because you avoid direct coupling between the `Activity` and the `Fragment`